Получение валидного URL на файл в удаленном репозитории GIT
Как (и можно ли в принципе) получить URL на файл для скачивания в какой то определенной ветке для передачи другому человеку имеющему доступ к удаленному репозиторию?
Есть ли какой то стандартный способ?

У меня репо гита на флешке, очевидно что никакого нормального URLа сделать не получится. А ваш гит где расположен?

на частном сервере. локальны репозиторий с серверным связан.

Добавляйте все уточнения в тело вопроса (нопка "править"). А сервер какой, гитлаб или еще что-то? У сервера есть белый IP?

какая разница что крутится на сервере и есть или нет у него белый IP? вопрос в том то и состоит "Есть или нет возможность получить URL на файл на удаленном репозитории стандартными средства GIT"

Нет, потому что git-репозиторий в общем случае не доступен по http. В частных случаях (GitHub, gitlab и тп) надо смотреть документацию конкретного сервера.

Если же говорить про протокол git, то в нём не предусмотрено скачивание отдельных файлов

в протоколе git не предусмотрено скачивание отдельных файлов - удовлетворен ответом
